# Showing $\hom_{F}\left(\prod_{i=1}^{n}V_i\ ,\prod_{j=1}^{m}W_j\right)\cong\prod_{i=1}^{n}\prod_{j=1}^{m}\hom_{F}(V_i,W_j)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, vector-space-isomorphism

$\newcommand{\Hom}{\text{Hom}}$
I want to prove the following result for finite products of vector spaces:

> $$\Hom_{F}\left(\prod_{i=1}^{n}V_i\ ,\prod_{j=1}^{m}W_j\right)\cong\prod_{i=1}^{n}\prod_{j=1}^{m}\Hom_{F}(V_i,W_j).\tag{1}$$

Here, $A\cong B$ denotes $A$ and $B$ are isomorphic. I am aware of the following two results:

> $$\Hom_{F}\left(V,\prod_{j=1}^{m}W_j\right)\cong\prod_{j=1}^{m}\Hom_{F}(V,W_j).\tag{2}$$
> $$\Hom_{F}\left(\prod_{i=1}^{n}V_i\ ,W\right)\cong\prod_{i=1}^{n}\Hom_{F}(V_i,W).\tag{3}$$

**My Attempt:**
Let $\Psi:\Hom_{F}\left(\prod_{i=1}^{n}V_i\ ,\prod_{j=1}^{m}W_j\right)\rightarrow\prod_{i=1}^{n}\prod_{j=1}^{m}\Hom_{F}(V_i,W_j)$ be defined by $\Psi(T)=(\pi_j T\theta_i)_{i=1,\dots,n,\ j=1,\dots,m}$. I wanted to show $\Psi$ is an isomorphism. Here, $\pi_j$ and $\theta_i$ are the $j$-th projection and the $i$-th injection defined as follows:

> $\pi_p:\prod_{k\in\Delta} V_k\rightarrow V_p$ such that $\pi(f)=f(p)$ for all $f$ in the product space.
> $\theta_q:V_q\rightarrow\prod_{k\in\Delta}V_k$ such that $\theta_q(\alpha)(i)=\begin{cases}
> \alpha, & \text{if} & i=q\\
> 0, & \text{if} & i\ne q
> \end{cases}$.
> Here, $\Delta$ is an arbitrary indexing set (which, in this context, is finite).

I could show that $\Psi$ is injective by showing $\Psi(S)=\Psi(T)$ implies $S=T$ for all $S,T$. But I do not see we can show that it is also surjective. I was trying to set $T$ equal to a sum as is usually done in the proofs of $(2) \& (3)$ but cannot find a suitable form that works.

Some help\alternate approach would be highly appreciated. TIA.

Comment: surjectivity is just existence in the universal property of the product/coproduct and injectivity is the uniqueness in the universal property. In particular it makes perfect sense that it is tough to write down surjectivity on the nose as all of these depend on the specific morphisms you pick in your defining diagram.

Comment: @Enkidu : So, do you mean, by the universal property, showing $\Psi$ is surjective is equivalent to just showing that such a $\Psi$ exists? Would that mean in the proof above, one doesn't need to show explicitly that $\Psi$ is surjective?

Comment: exactly, if you have a tupel of morphisms on the right (btw. thank god that those products are finite, otherwise you get into real trouble) there EXISTS a UNIQUE map making the diagram commute, that is welldefinednes and injectivity of your map. 

Now assume you got a map, then composing with all the projections and inclusions from your diagram (again, the products are finite, so coproducts and all is fine) gives you a diagram that would suffice the univ property and BAM there is surjectivity. (also, the same argument holds in every abelian cat)

Comment: @Enkidu : Great. Thanks for the clarification. And yes, I'm awareness of the troubles with infinite products. I've working on this a while and found that only $(2)$ can be generalized to infinite products but nothing else.

Comment: @Enkidu : Btw, I wanted to mention, in case you've the time, if you post your comments above as an answer I'd happily accept it. Your comments really helped clarify some things for me. :)

Comment: awesome, sorry writing that stuff down in detail (like one should for an answer) is very annoying, but I think you got the jist. btw. you can also generalize part (1) but there you need a coproduct inside and a product outside if I remember correctly, and that is precisely why you get into troubles, these two notions dont agree anymore and you get a mix of product and coproduct. In the end this is a result of being additive covariant or contravariant, respectively admitting an adjoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I got asked to post it as answer: (sorry for being very handwavy, currently dont have the time to do all the diagrams and dont know if tikz works here)

if you have a tupel of morphisms on the left (btw. thank god that those products are finite, otherwise you get into real trouble) there EXISTS by universal property a UNIQUE map making the diagram commute, that is welldefinednes and injectivity of your map.

Now assume you got a map on the right, then composing with all the projections and inclusions from your diagram (again, the products are finite, so products are coproducts and all is fine) gives you a diagram that would suffice the universal property and BAM there is surjectivity (uniqueness tells you the induced morphism must be the morphism you started with).

Final funfact: the same argument holds in every additive cat!

Answer (score 1):

If you set $V = \prod V_i$ and $W = \prod W_j$, and believe (2) and (3), then
$$\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom} \Hom(V,W) \stackrel{(2)}{=} \prod_i \Hom(V_i, W) \stackrel{(3)}{=} \prod_i \prod_j \Hom(V_i, W_j).$$
If you follow the given isomorphisms of (2) and (3), this should hopefully also give you the isomorphism you require.

*Here is a subtle note:* To only prove that the spaces are isomorphic as $F$-vector spaces, it would actually be sufficient to count their dimensions. Suppose $\dim V_i = n_i, \dim W_j = m_j$, then both sides have dimension
$$\left(\sum_i n_i\right)\left(\sum_j m_j\right) = \sum_{i,j} n_i m_j,$$
because dimensions are additive for (finite) products and multiplicative when applying $\Hom$ (think of matrices). So at this point is just follows from linear algebra, that the two spaces are abstractly isomorphic. However, this is probably not the result you want to have, because you want a *special* homomorphism to be an isomorphism, which has certain naturality properties.

Comment: You are correct in thinking that I need specifically $\Psi$ to be an isomorphism. But I am happy to learn that one can also abstractly argue that these spaces are isomorphic.